From Taylor Series to Rational Function
I am considering the reverse process of the Taylor expansion of a rational function.
Question: suppose that I have
$$
f(x) = a_{0}+a_{1}x+a_{2}x^{2}+\cdots,
$$
and I know that $f(x)$ is a rational function (i.e. $f(x)=\frac{h(x)}{g(x)}$ is quotient of two polynomials) and I know the formula for $a_{n}$. How can I explicitly find $h(x)$ and $g(x)$?
More specifically, the formula of $a_{n}$ is the following: there is a square matrix $A$, and $a_{n}$ is the $(1,1)$-entry of $A^{n}$, i.e.
$$
a_{n} = (A^{n})_{1,1}
$$
In this case, how can we write $f(x)$ as a rational function?
Example: Let
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Then, $a_{n}=2^{n-1}=(1,2,4,8,\cdots)$, and $f(x) =x+2x^{2}+4x^{3}+8x^{4}+\cdots= \frac{x}{1-2x}$. However, I got the expression of $f(x)= \frac{x}{1-2x}$ by guessing. Is there a concrete way of finding such $f(x)$?
Thanks very much for your help!

The function you gave here( in the example) is just a simple GP summation. Your function will return a normal real number only if the common ratio, here $2x$ is less than $1$ or more than $-1$, or $|x|<\frac12$.

You say that you are really interested in the case where $a_n=(A^n)_{1,1}$. In that case we have $a_0=1$.
The you want the $(1,1)$ entry in
$$
I+Ax+A^2x^2+\dots=\frac{I}{I-Ax}=\frac{1}{\det(I-Ax)}\mathop{\rm adj}(I-Ax).
$$
Now $\mathop{\rm adj}(I-Ax)$ is a matrix polynomial which we can calculate, and then find it's $(1,1)$ entry, which will be a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$; and then we can divide by the polynomial $\det(I-Ax)$ of degree $n$.
[All this is generic and formal; there may be exceptional cases, and convergence may or may not be a problem.]
